# Only activate Vue getters when not undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm not sure how to better phrase this title... =x But here's my issue.

I have a getter in my vuex store like so,

```
myTurn( state ) {
  if ( state.roomObj.next !== undefined ) {
    return state.roomObj.next === state.uid
  }
},
```

The state.roomObj.next is something that is sometimes available, and sometimes not. That is why I have to check if it is undefined or else it is going to cause an error in trying to get the value and hang the application.

But the problem is I have a whole list of such getters and I have to check for undefined for each... It feels a little wrong when all my getters have an extra if statement... My question is,

1. shouldn't it be by default only processing if it's not undefined. Or shouldn't it be a non-breaking error and just return a NaN or something to the getters' result?
2. Or is there a better way to check for undefined property so I don't have to have an if statement for every getter?

Comment: You might consider placing the undefined check in its own function/method and then do something like `return checkUndefined(state.roomObj.next) && state.roomObj.next === state.uid;` where `checkUndefined(val) { return val !== undefined; }`. Encapsulating your undefined check this way allows you to reduce repetition and more easily modify behavior if needed, and your individual getters won't have the if statements cluttering them up.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
myTurn( state ) {
  return state.roomObj['next'] ? state.roomObj['next'] === state.uid : false
}
```

maybe this also:

```
myTurn( state ) {
  return state.roomObj['next'] && state.roomObj['next'] === state.uid
}
```

---

But:

> The state.roomObj.next is something that is sometimes available, and sometimes not.

This is really bad. Improve your app that `state.roomObj.next` will be always available, but sometimes false, sometimes true. Anything you need, but always defined. And you can remove this unncessary condition in all your getters.

Comment: The thing is I have a object in [next] that lies on the firebase server which is synced realtime to my state. And before the first [next] object is added, it returns back as undefined even if I pushed in an empty object, etc. I'm guessing they don't register empty stuff as 'defined'. And if I pushed a dummy object, I would have to figure out if that needs to be overwritten or is that the actual [next] object. Not sure what's the best way to fix this other than just checking for undefined.

Comment: So, dont push an empty object. Push `next: {uid: false}` at least. Then you  need not to check anything in getter. Just return the `next.uid` value and in program do something like:
`if (next.uid) {
  //do something on this uid
 } else {
  // no uid, do something else - default action
  }`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I shall try that. Thanks!

Comment: @KelvinZhao Glad to help!